# How to integrate automation test cases in Azure Devops Test Plan

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, devops, test-plan

I am trying to integrate Selenium testng test cases with azure test plan but I am not able to, I have Build Pipeline and release pipeline but getting one error when trying to run test cases from test plan which is  - Identifying tests:Found 0 automated test(s).